# Showing "We couldn't estimate the gas" error in estimated fee consumption field while executing a contract in ethereum wallet

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, out-of-gas, gas-estimate

I have tried creating contracts in ethereum wallet but sometimes it shows an error while executing those contracts. The error says `It seems this transaction will fail. If you submit it, it may consume all the gas you provide`. Can anyone help me with this issue?

My smart contract is like:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
contract MyToken {
        function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
    }

    contract TransferToken{
        function sendTheToken(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value)public returns(string) {
            address tokenContractAddress = <MyTokenaddress>
            MyToken token = MyToken (tokenContractAddress);
            bool sendSuccess = token.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
            if(sendSuccess=true) return 'success';
            else return 'Failure';
        }
    }
```

In the above contract MyToken is a contract that I have created earlier for crypto-currencies.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }

contract MyToken {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 2;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    function MyToken(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        string tokenSymbol
    ) public {
        totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                
        name = tokenName;                                
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               
    }


    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        require(_to != 0x0);
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }


    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);  
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This usually occurs when your `require` checks or your contract `throws`. Mist provides max gas limit much more than your transaction needs (aI am not sure of the exact figure, you can see this while sending tx) so when the estimated gas of the transaction becomes equal to max gas supplied, Mist gives this error.

Comment: I think the require checks are not throwing. Can you tell me what to do if the estimated gas of the transaction becomes equal to mas gas supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably some error in the method you are trying to invoke. This mostly occurs when the `require()` in the function is not satisfied or some other visible error occurs. If you can share the code or at least the function, I can help you with that.

**Edit (after the code was posted):**

The `transferFrom()` has a `require()` that needs to be satisfied in order to get executed. The requirement is that the calling address should have sufficient allowance in order to proceed with the transfer of funds.

Though the function checks if the value returned is true or false, only when the `transferFrom()` method satisfies the `require()` it will return `true`. Otherwise, the function will just throw and not return `false`. When the scenario where it will throw, the error `"It seems this transaction will fail. If you submit it,it may consume all the gas you provide"` occurs.

The recommended way is

```
contract TransferToken{
    function sendTheToken(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value)public returns(string) {
        address tokenContractAddress = <MyTokenaddress>
        MyToken token = MyToken (tokenContractAddress);
        token.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
    }
}
```

If the requirement is satisfied, then the function call will succeed. If it fails, It will throw and return the remaining gas.

If you just looking to debug the contract and don't want to modify the `sendTheToken()` function then, you can modify the `transferFrom()` method this way to the below code.

```
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        if(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]) {
            allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
            _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Either way, no need of the bool success in the `transferFrom()` method. You can directly return the boolean value. Saves some gas.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the code.I am a beginner so I have no idea what is wrong with this.

Comment: I just saw the code. The code seems to be fine from the overall view. Which function did you try to invoke when you go the error?

Comment: I got the error when i invoked the sendTheToken function of TransferToken contract.

Comment: @MonicaMohandas Since the explanation was a bit big. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I have tried that. Now I don't have the issue of gas instead the tokens are not getting transferred. Do you know why?

Comment: Awesome! You will have to post it as a seperate question and accept this if this served your purpose.

Comment: @MonicaMohandas or if you can link your tx id where the tokens weren't transferred I can help with that.